# How does SwiftUI's declarative syntax actually work?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've been following [Apple's SwiftUI tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui), and the syntax seems really nice to use. In fact, the only problem I have with it is that I don't really understand how it works!

We can start off with the simplest possible `View`:

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world")
    }
}
```

I understand what's going on here: `body` is a read-only computed property, and the single `Text()` expression is used as the return value of the getter. We can write this out "long-hand", and it still works:

```
struct ExampleView: some View {
    var body: some View {
        get {
            return Text("Hello world")
        }
    }
}
```

Going back to the first version, instead of just returning a plain `Text` view, we can wrap it in a `VStack`:

```
struct ExampleView: some View {
    var body: some View { 
        VStack { 
            Text("Hello world") 
        }
    } 
}
```

Now we are passing a lambda/closure to the `VStack` constructor, which again implicitly returns a `Text` object. So far, so good. But what I don't understand is what's going on here:

```
// ???
struct ExampleView: some View {
    var body: some View { 
        VStack { 
            Text("Hello") // (1)
            Text("World") 
        }
    } 
}
```

This looks for all the world as if the code on line (1) is calling the `Text` constructor, building the object and then immediately throwing it away. The `Text` object doesn't (appear to) register itself with the parent `VStack` or anything like that in order to be displayed -- and yet some magic is clearly occurring, because the above results in two lines of text in output.

Can anybody enlighten me as to what exactly is happening here?